# How to rewrite URLs according to DB records in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting, wildfly

I am developing a JAX-RS multi-domain application. This application is supposed to be addressed by different domain names and shall handle these domains differently. Each domain is a record in DB and maps the domain name to UUID. Records of all domains are set to the same server IP. UUIDs are used internally as a path parameter (for example: https://{IP}/{uuid}).

I would like to achieve the following state:

`https://domain1.com/{someResource} --> https://{serverIP}/domain/123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000/{someResouce}`

The illustration case:
The user accesses the resource on the URL https://my-domain.com/rest/v1/details and the server serves the details about the current domain (and similarly in other requests).

My idea was to implement a ContainerRequestFilter which would add information about requested URL (and hostname) like it works in authentication filters. The second approach was to use the Ocpsoft Rewrite library but I failed in setting it up and the documentation is not very rich in this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi achieved it by using javax.servlet.Filter

Check it out:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@WebFilter(filterName = "MyAwesomeFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class MyAwesomeFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        final String s = request.getRequestURI() + "/addedSomething"
        request.getRequestDispatcher(s).forward(request, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```